# Use declared variable in a VBA formula

Tags: excel, variables, formula, vba

```
Dim LastRowC As Long
Dim LastRowE As Long
Dim Deelnemernr As Long
    LastRowC = Range("C1048576").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    Deelnemernr = Cells(LastRowC, 3).Offset(0, 4).Select
```

I can manage to select the variable cell which I want to use in my formula below. So the code above works.

```
LastRowE = Range("E1048576").End(xlUp).Row + 1
Cells(LastRowE, 5).Formula = "=Index(E:E,Match(Deelnemernr,G:G,0))"
```

What I cannot seem to do is use the variable declared above as Deelnemernr in my Match formula. When I use a fixed cell (for example G12) in stead of Deelnemernr the formula does work. Can anyone tell my how the refer to a declared variable in a formula?

Answer (score 2):

You need to get the `Deelnemernr` variable outside the double quotes `"`.

Also, there's no need to use `Select` here :

```
Deelnemernr = Cells(LastRowC, 3).Offset(0, 4).Select
```

just get the value of that cell by:

```
Deelnemernr = Cells(LastRowC, 3).Offset(0, 4).Value
```

Try the code below:

```
LastRowC = Range("C1048576").End(xlUp).Row + 1
Deelnemernr = Cells(LastRowC, 3).Offset(0, 4).Value

LastRowE = Range("E1048576").End(xlUp).Row + 1
Cells(LastRowE, 5).Formula = "=Index(E:E,Match(" & Deelnemernr & ",G:G,0))"
```